# Open a JQueryUI Dialog and have it populate itself from DB

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog

I have a list of companies and I want to be able to open a dialog to be able to edit their details.
This opens the dialog:

```
$('#company_details').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
```

Only binds the dialog to the first instance of , not every one.

And then, how can I pass the dialog an ID so I can then run an AJAX query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have more than one company, then you need some way to select each - like a button or an image. This button or image or other link could have it's own id. For example:

```
<tr>
    <td>Company ABC</td>
    <td><button class='details' id='12345'>Details</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Company XYZ</td>
    <td><button class='details' id='45454'>Details</button></td>
</tr>
```

Then your code would be:

```
$(".details").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    --> insert what you want to do <---
}):
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you mean, but try using a class selector instead of an id:

`$('.company_details')`

instead of

```
$('#company_details')
```

If that doesn't work could you update your question with the html you're using?

There are a few ways to pass in the id, check http://docs.jquery.com/Core and look for the `data(name,value)` method. You can set the id in there then retrieve it when you need it later.